# Write v-if condition in HTML using less code

Tags: vue.js

I need to decide whether it is going to be created `<button>` or `<a>` based on `href` attribute (check if it is forwarded). I am not able to post original code here because there are bunch of self made components used inside it and therefore it won't make any sense, but sample of it would be something like this:

```
<a v-if="href" class="btn" v-on:click="clicked">
        //bunch of repetitive code
        @{{button_label}}
</a>
<button v-else class="btn" v-on:click="clicked">
        //bunch of repetitive code
        @{{button_label}}
</button>
```

Is there a way to write only once all that code between two `<a>` or `<button>` tags and checking if I should create each of those two tags on the start of the code? (One way would be creating a JS function which would be triggered on button click and return a `href` if it exists, but I am not allowed to do that, so that is why I explicitly ask if it is possible to do this in HTML part of code)

My idea was to do this:

```
<a v-if="href" class="btn" v-on:click="clicked">
<button v-else class="btn" v-on:click="clicked">
    //bunch of repetitive code
        @{{button_label}}
</a v-if="href">
</button v-else>
```

but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: `</a v-if="href">` and `</button v-else>` just need to be `</a>` and `</button>` The conditional is a directive, essentially an attribute. You don't do `<a class="blah"> Some Text </a class="blah">`

Comment: If I remove conditions from closing tags, will it know which one should it use (based on which was created in start) and will the other one, which was never opened, cause problems?
Also, why do you say I shouldn't set classes inside those tags?

Comment: why not create new component with all this repetitive code?

Comment: @niksrb Forst point, yes. HTML is hierarchical. Second point (setting classes) - Missed the point entirely. You do not set the class on the **closing** tag, it was an example about incorrectly using attributes.

Comment: @Sousuke okay and than what? I haven't resolved my issue, it's just gonna be less code here, but still I have to check if I should create `<a>` then new component, than in else part `<button>` and again new component. How can I hava line which is calling that new component only once?

Comment: @ggdx Oh you were talking about closing tags. Okey, I understand, thanks.

Comment: `<SomeComponent :type="buttonOrARef"></SomeComponent>` then inside that single component, place your reusable stuff.

Comment: @ggdx Can you write your last comment as an answer, but also including the `buttonOrARef` function with it's body, I still do not understand how I am going to decide which one (`<button>` or `<a>`) is going to be created.

Comment: actually you don't have to toggle the two elements. You can just only use the <a>, why do you have to use another button, if they have the same logic.

Comment: @Pengcheng Maybe you are right. I can always achieve to have button look by adding suitable classes to `<a>` tag, right? I can make `<a>` look like bootstrap info, danger, success etc. buttons ?
If this is the case, then why does `<button>` tag even exists...

Comment: @niksrb, sure, you have the click event, just make sure when the click event is triggered, if the default behavior of <a> needs to be prevented. And for the styling you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```
<component 
  :is="href ? 'a' : 'button'" 
  :href="href">
  // bunch of code
</component>
```

This allows you to use a different component (or element) based on a condition.

Comment: Well, this is great! I didn't know about this. Thanks!